# Несколько условий в тернарной операции

Tags: php

Возникла ошибка после добавления еще одного условия при помощи тернарного оператора **"?"**
Что я сделал не так и как исправить ошибку?

```
<?php 
 
$a = 2;
$b = 2;

$z = 

$a < $b ?  $a + $b: 
$a === $b ? $a + 2: 
$a - $b;

echo $z;

?>
```

Comment: ...Ошибка какая?

Comment: Fatal error: Unparenthesized `a ? b : c ? d : e` is not supported. Use either `(a ? b : c) ? d : e` or `a ? b : (c ? d : e)`

Comment: в тексте вполне написано что не так и что надо делать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Непонятная конструкция малочитаема людьми.

Надо заботиться о других и расставлять круглые скобки, чтобы понимать какое выражение где находится.

Собственно об этом (о скобках) и говорит текст ошибки.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137854/discussion-on-answer-by-------).